# Timer writes in log twice

Tags: c#, winforms, timer

Everything works fine except for one thing.  My program prints "player hit" 2 times then "mob hit" 2 times and then "player hit" 2 times again and so forth.  I want it to type "player Hit" "mob Hit" "player Hit" "mob Hit" and so on.  I can't see why it types it 2 times.

My code looks like this:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        int Rase1 = 0;

        InitializeComponent();

        timer1.Tick += new EventHandler(timer1_Tick);
        timer1.Interval = (1000);
        timer1.Enabled = false;

        timer2.Tick += new EventHandler(timer2_Tick);
        timer2.Interval = (1000);
        timer2.Enabled = false;
    }

    private void buttonChoseRase_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Rase1 == 0)
        {
            Rase1 = 1;
            Rase Rase = new Race(this);
            Rase.Show();
        }
        else if (Race1 >= 1)
        {
            buttonChoseRase.Enabled = false;

            Rebirth Reb = new Rebirth(this);
            Reb.Show();
        }
    }

    private void buttonStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBoxCombatLog.Text = "";

        buttonStart.Enabled = false;
        buttonStop.Enabled = true;

        timer1.Start();

        timer2.Stop();
    }

    private void buttonStop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        buttonStart.Enabled = true;
        buttonStop.Enabled = false;

        timer1.Stop();
        timer2.Stop();
    }

    private void LogWrite(string txt)
    {
        textBoxCombatLog.AppendText(txt + Environment.NewLine);
        textBoxCombatLog.SelectionStart = textBoxCombatLog.Text.Length;
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LogWrite(TimeDate + "Player Hit \n");

        timer1.Stop();

        timer2.Start();
    }

    private void timer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LogWrite(TimeDate + "Mob Hit \n");

        timer2.Stop();

        timer1.Start();
    }

    private string TimeDate
    {
        get { return "[" + DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss") + "]" + ": "; }
    }
}
```

---

Here is what is looks like running, and no matter what I do, everything shows up twice:

[image]

Comment: You don't need to repeat the first part of your question in the second part, also, I see this is not the full code of your project, because we don't know what Rase and Rebirth are.

Comment: @Rafael Fixed the redundant text bit.

Answer (score 2):

You've attached the event handler to the `Tick` event of the timer through designer in addition to through the code file itself.  You need to remove one of the two.  *Either* attach the event handler in code *or* attach it through the designer.

Comment: but that dont matter, its just button that opens a new windo.

Comment: @JohannesBjärehall Um...no.  The `Tick` event handlers of the two timers is where you write to the log.  I'm not referring to the button click handlers at all.

Comment: wait wait wait, im not really a pro at this, so i do not really understand what you suggests me to do, could you like explain it in some other way ?

Comment: @Servy The OP didn't reply, but I'm happy to report I had the same problem and your solution was right on target. I had set my Tick event handling in the Properties window, and also attached it in code. Deleting it from the Properties window did the trick. Thanks!